# Trigger event when the state of child of another component changed in react

Tags: reactjs

Let say I have two components called A and B.

B has a status which keeps changing and I would like to pass the status to A so that I can trigger event when certain condition is met.

How do I keep monitoring/getting state of child from another component in React?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying about child and parent or about components on the same level?
And what have you tried?

Comment: They should be on the same level. I have tried "componentWillReceiveProps" to get the status of B in A but I failed.

Comment: If your components on the same level, you can achieve this with [redux](http://redux.js.org/)/[flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) or with common parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When component on the same level:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      status: "B not clicked"
    }
    this.componentBchangeHandler = this.componentBchangeHandler.bind(this);
  }
  componentBchangeHandler(value) {
    this.setState({ status: value })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ComponentA status={this.state.status} />
        <ComponentB componentBchangeHandler={this.componentBchangeHandler} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const ComponentA = (props) => <div>{props.status}</div>;
const ComponentB = (props) => <div onClick={() => props.componentBchangeHandler("some val")}>click me</div>;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/k29mn21pov

And check out the documents I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I want B to pass a value to outside?

Comment: Something like this:

componentBchangeHandler(value) {
    this.setState({ status: value })
}

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a parent-child relationship, all you'd have to do is define a function that changes state on A and pass it as prop to B, like so:

```
class A extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      changed: false,
    }
  }

  _statusChange = () => this.setState({ changed: !this.state.changed });

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <span>State on A: { this.state.changed.toString() }</span>
        <B changeHandler={this._statusChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class B extends Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.changeHandler}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const App = () => (
    <A />
);
```

If they should be on the same level, by convention, you should define a third component, wrap A and B in it, again passing state as props between them.